# Why have all the colors from the picture disappeared?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, cs6

[image: ALL colors from picture are disappeared!]

Hello, can anyone tell me why are the colors from picture disappeared? How can I bring them back? Thanks!

Comment: Hi there and welcome to GD! Have you checked your colour-space? And that it is set to CMYK or RGB?

Comment: O'Reilly, strange question..

Comment: @Vnovak was it? I thought s/he had a bunch of coloured lines that magically lost the colours.

Comment: @RandomO'Reilly, I guess you just overseen the screenshot - CMYK(Outline) at top :)

Comment: @Vnovak hahaha! I must be blind as a bat! Good job I only made it a comment and not an answer. That would be too much egg on my face :D

Answer (score 11):

You switched into wireframe (outline) mode. It is quite useful sometime. You can switch between them via Ctrl(Cmd)+Y.